# Add author to pdf

Tags: macos, pdf, pages

I produce a quarterly bulletin, which I publish as a pdf. This is written in Pages 4.3 and exported. Previous issues on OS X 10.8 have my name as Author. Recent issues on OS X 10.9 show unknown author.

How can I change this on new exports?

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't fix your export problem, but this is a fairly easy workaround.
You can easily edit PDF metadata using a very simple automator workflow:

1. Open Automator and create a new Service
2. Set 'Service receives selected' to ***PDF files*** 'in' ***Finder.app***
3. Search for 'set meta' and drag and drop the ***Set PDF Metadata*** action to the right
4. At the bottom under 'Options' select ***Show this action when workflow runs***
5. Save the service and give it a name
6. Optionally, create a keyboard shortcut under ***System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts***, select 'Services' from the left pane and look for your service under 'Files and Folders'

Now you can right click a PDF file and under services select your service, or select a PDF file and use your newly created shortcut to launch your Service.

Hope this helps.

[image: Set PDF Metadata action in Automator]

[image: Keyboard shortcuts preference pane]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My original post (before someone edited it out) indicated I had found references to using an Automator workflow - to prevent answers suggesting this. I have since written one, and it works, but it is tedious to have to run every time you export.

Comment: Why would someone edit that out of your question? Oh well, maybe my answer will help others in the future.   But you're right, this isn't ideal. I'll look into it a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

I use Pages 5.2 and notice that there is a preference for Author, however in my testing (under Mavericks) PDFs created by Pages do not inherit this value.

I think you are going to have to use a third party tool to edit the Author meta data after you create the PDF.

It doesn't appear you can do this in Preview.app or Adobe Reader.  You can do this in Acrobat Pro ($), Automator (with the "Set PDF Metadata" function) or [PDFInfo](http://www.sybrex.com/products/macgui/infomanager/) (free).  I am sure that are other programs as well.